# how to handle a confirm box which is the output of another confirm box in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, confirm

[1[][2]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yAzY.png)Scenario:: Web page asking for a confirm box (OK /cancel) then if i click on "OK" it is asking for another confirm box (OK /cancel)

here am able to handle the first confirm box by using "alert.accept()"

But am not knowing how to handle the second confirm box.

Could someone help me out with this..

Comment: Is the second confirm box also an alert? Or a dialog of some sort? This will go a lot faster for you if you can provide a website (hopefully its public).

Comment: Its a confirm box asking for (OK or Cancel)

Comment: This is why it could take awhile. It *could* be a system dialog, or it *could* be a pure HTML dialog. You have to figure out which it is. If it is a system dialog, selenium cannot interact with it. If it is HTML, selenium can probably control it. Can you tell which type it is?

Comment: system dialog  box

Comment: Then you leave the realm of selenium (at least temporarily) to deal with the dialog. Try Autoit, ctypes, or other extension to interact with the system dialog. Then when it is dismissed, you can return to controlling the web page with selenium. [Here is a link that might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48229446/python-selenium-webpage-with-windows-security).

Comment: Can you share your code attempts to handle both the first and second _confirm boxes_?

Comment: alert = self.driver.switch_to.alert
assert "WPS requires SSID broadcasting in order to work. If you make this change, WPS will become inaccessible. Do you want to continue?" in alert.text
time.sleep(5)
alert.accept()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
  
wait.until(EC.alert_is_present())
alert = self.driver.switch_to.alert

assert "Are you sure that you do not want any wireless security on your network? This setting is typically used for wireless hot spots that are open to public access. Do you want to continue?" in alert.text
time.sleep(5)
alert.accept()